# how to construct two dimensional lists using the example ive given

Tags: python

I am stuck in question relating to the two dimension list, the questions are Write a program that constructs a two dimensional list containing 5 lists each containing 5 elements. The value of the ith element in the jth list should be j×5+i using the code.
Adapt the program from the previous question so that it asks the user for two dimensions, then constructs a two dimensional list with the speciﬁed dimensions with the values as described in the previous questions. 
As I am a new to programming please can you help me.

```
#create a variable called a of type list
a = []


for I in range(5):
    #append an empty list to a 
    a.append([])
    for j in range (5):
        #append 0 to the ith list of a 
        a[I].append(0)
#print a 
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work

```
x = input('Type a value for the number of lines: ')
y = input('Type a value for the number of columns: ')

#create a variable called a of type list
a = []

for i in range(x):
    #append an empty list to a 
    a.append([])
    for j in range (y):
        #append 0 to the ith list of a 
        a[i].append(j*5+i)
#print a 
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) wins here:

```
[[j*5+i for j in range(5)] for i in range(5)]
```